# return variable argument as another value?

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
$set = "argument";
function imp_set($set){
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT $set FROM settings WHERE id=1");
    if($sql){
        $res=mysql_result($sql,0);
    }
    $set = $res;
}
```

I want to `echo("$argument");` to display `$res` value.
Thanks.

Comment: `mysql` commands are deprecated. For security purposes you should use the newer `mysqli` or `PDO` commands. Also, where is `$argument` defined? I don't see it anywhere in your code.

Comment: So you are passing in the name of the variable that you want the value to be saved to?  Correct?

Comment: Do you want to access `$argument` inside or outside of the function?

Comment: it's just for indicate that $argument is $set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$set = "argument";
function imp_set($set){
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT $set FROM settings WHERE id=1");
    if($sql){
        $res=mysql_result($sql,0);
    }
    $$set = $res;
    echo $argument;
}
```

With that said, this is an odd request, and you're also not returning anything from the function.  Very few people use php "variable variables" because they are confusing and rarely worth the trouble, considering the obfuscation they introduce.

Comment: is there any other solution?

Comment: A typical solution would be to return an associative array: return array($set => $res);