# How to return function's argument as variable by another value?

Tags: php, function, variables

to be more clear .... :

```
$var = "value";
function func($var){
    $sql=mysql_query("...$var...");
    $res = mysql_result($sql);
    //$var = $res;
}
echo("$value");
```

I want from the last line to display `$res` value, Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more clear? What is `$ssn`? How do you plan to call `func()`?

Comment: What is the $ssn variable that you echo here for?

Comment: You posted this exact question 55 minutes ago. Duplicate [stackoverflow.com/questions/13885050/...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885050/return-variable-argument-as-another-value)

Comment: I'll say it since I know someone else will. It is recommended that you use pdo or mysqli instead of the mysql libraries because they are deprecated and less secure.

Comment: @user1904946 You should edit it then so that people understand what you were asking rather than post the same question twice with different wording. [Stack Overflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 0):

by assigning $var="value" doesn't mean that is what is passed into the function.  You have to call the function with any value you want and that value will be put into the $var variable within the func function.

What if you did:

```
$var = "value";
function func($var){
    $sql=mysql_query("...$var...");
    $res = mysql_result($sql);
    return $res;
}

$ssn = func($var);  
# you could also do func("value");
echo("$ssn");
```